# replaceWith Automatically Closes the Tag

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have 3 divs and I want to replace the first div with an opening tag of another div and the third with the closing tag. This is what I meant:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

When I tried to replace (using replaceWith()) the first div with `<div class="foo">` and the third with `</div>`, jQuery somewhat misinterpret it as:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
```

While what I actually want is:

```
<div class="foo">
 <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with whole elements rather than pieces of HTML code. Another way to think about it is:

```
// Get the div you want
var good = $('div:eq(1)');
// Remove the others
$('div').not(good).remove();
// Wrap the div you want
good.wrap('<div class="foo">');
```

If there are multiple divs between the first and the last, you may do this:

```
$('div:first').replaceWith('<div class="foo">');
$('div.foo').nextAll('div').appendTo('div.foo');
$('div.foo :last').remove();
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TBMHt/

Comment: But in this case I don't know what or how many is in between the 2 divs so that method can't be used. Is there a way to find what is between two divs?

Comment: @Warrantica, added an alternative for that case ;)